# Spawning threads to process data

Tags: java, multithreading, datetime

I have a class that spawns threads to process data. I am working on instrumentation code. When the process is started, `time = System.currentTimeMillis();` When it completes, `time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;` I have a method to retrieve this time:

```
/**
 * Get the time taken for process to complete
 * 
 * @return Time this process has run if running; time it took to complete if not
 */
public long getRunTime() {
   return processRunning? System.currentTimeMillis() - time : time;
}
```

Is this a clear use of the ternary operator? Is my [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) comment clear?

Comment: should document your units

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the method has a return value even if the code is not finished processing the first line of your javadoc ought not read "Get the time taken for process to complete" but perhaps rather "Get the current or total processing time" or something of that nature? I also agree with Bert F's comment, but if there were clear comments explaining the behavior and you don't intend on exposing start and end times individually then there's no reason to waste an extra variable; you can either keep the code as it is and add comments or optionally get rid of the boolean "processRunning" and instead use your completedTime/runTime variable to establish the fact that it's still running. All minor gripes, all in all.

Answer (score 6):

I have no problem the ternary operator.

But it is hard to tell that the result is what the comments is saying. Without having a context on what time is (which is a bad variable name) it is hard to understand the result of the function.

time: Bad variable name. Time of what?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the method sometimes returns a timestamp (`time`) and sometimes it returns a duration (difference between timestamps) (assuming that `time` is always a timestamp - if not, then this issue simply moves to `time` having a dual definition).

Comment: What about `processRunning? System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime : completedTime - startTime;`

Comment: Works for me, as does `processRunning ? System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime : runTime;`

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of style and taste but I'd rather go with

```
public long getRunTime() {
   if(processRunning)
     return System.currentTimeMillis() - time; 

     return time;
}
```

I just think this reads easier, and its easier to comment this. Now set me on fire for multiple return statements :D

Comment: Actually, I don't have a problem with this style. I do have a problem with multiple exit points spread throughout the function.

Comment: Looks a little odd without the `else`, IMHO.